# Status bar and YoutubeAndroidPlayerAPI

Tags: android, youtube, android-youtube-api

I have designed my application to work in fullscreen mode. No status bar and no action bars are visible. This suppose a problem since every time a load a video from youtube ussing YoutubeAndroidPlayerAPI the status bar appears.

I have a viewpager inside a fragment which loads youtube thumbnails. Everytime a thumbnail is pressed, i call youtubePlayerView.initialize with the following code:

```
@Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) container.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.youtubeitem, null);

         ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.youThumbail);
         imageView.setTag(position);
         imageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(final View v) {

                    mContainerThumbs.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    youtubePlayerView.bringToFront();
                    playerContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    youtubePlayerView.setTag(campaign.getVideos().get(Integer.parseInt(v.getTag().toString())));
                    youtubePlayerView.initialize(act.getResources().getString(R.string.youKEY), new OnInitializedListener(){

                        @Override
                        public void onInitializationFailure(Provider arg0, YouTubeInitializationResult arg1) {

                            Log.e("fail","fail");
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onInitializationSuccess(Provider arg0, YouTubePlayer arg1, boolean arg2) {

                            youtubePlayer = arg1;
                            arg1.loadVideo(campaign.getVideos().get(Integer.parseInt(v.getTag().toString())));
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
         imageLoader.displayImage("http://img.youtube.com/vi/"+campaign.getVideos().get(position)+"/hqdefault.jpg", imageView, options, animateFirstListener);

         ((ViewPager) container).addView(view, 0);
         return view;
    }
```

The problem like i said before is that the application is showing in fullscreen mode, but whenever i press one thumbnail (i.e. OnClickListener of imageView is fired), the status bar is showed. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, setting the flag YouTubePlayer.FULLSCREEN_FLAG_CONTROL_ORIENTATION after initialization seems to solve the problem =)

```
...
@Override
public void onInitializationSuccess(Provider arg0, YouTubePlayer arg1, boolean arg2) {
    youtubePlayer = arg1;
    youtubePlayer.setFullscreenControlFlags(YouTubePlayer.FULLSCREEN_FLAG_CONTROL_ORIENTATION);
    arg1.loadVideo(campaign.getVideos().get(Integer.parseInt(v.getTag().toString())));
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to reset all the flags in onInitializationSuccess, to never show the status bar at all:

```
player.setFullscreenControlFlags(-1);
```